# How to make a QR code reader

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to make a QR code reader for android app.
if you all have any information to create it please share with me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is the most popular lib for it. It allows using the barcode scanner as intent so it doesnt require that much work either.

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Getting-Started-Developing