# How to implement shopping cart in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am new in android. My app is basically is to scan the QR code to obtain product information such as the image, name, description and price and choose to add to cart and continue to do so(scan the qrcode) till user choose to end shopping and click to proceed to cart and will be shown the total prices of the items selected. User then can click either to edit the cart or proceed to the checkout. I have been searching tutorial  but cannot find a complete one. Can anyone guide me through proper code how could i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you will ever find a complete tutorial for the your task. However, a quick googling led me to [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted) which can be used for processing barcode. I didnt go through the examples provided there, but I believe they are easy to understand.

**Edit:**
  This is an exact duplicate of another question in SO. [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792809/how-to-make-a-qr-code-reader)
Now if that answer seems not enough for you, I think you are new to Android. Just google Android and you will find plenty of tutorials available. Start with Layouts, Activities, Intents, Bundles, Event Handling. To build what you want you would need a blend of many such small small things. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You will most probably wont find one single complete A to Z tutorial satisfying ALL of your app requirements .
But you can search for code/tutorial implementing parts of your app , like reading QR code , proceeding to next item etc . You will have to  figure yourself out how it all comes together.

[QR reader app on Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.unveil&hl=en)

Comment: I cannot find anything .Can u provide me the link of tutorial how i implement the shopping cart plz.